# Problem with layout constructing in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout for my recyclerview item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_hotel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_hotel_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_hotel"
            tools:text="Belleclaire Hotel" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/include_stars_set"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_hotel_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_hotel_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_hotel_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/include"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include"
            tools:text="250 West 77th Street, Manhattan" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_hotel_address"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_hotel_address"
            tools:text="100.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_suites_available_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_suites_availability"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_distance"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_distance" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_suites_available"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_suites_available_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_suites_available_label" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_hotel_image"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_hotel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_hotel" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

It seems like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzrXR.png)

However after building I have this view:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGN3A.png)

As you can see, I see only a half of my progressbar after I'm trying to dowload an image to my iv_hotel with a help of Glide.
How can I solve this problem? I'm a bit bad at xml guidelines understanding, so I'm asking for a help(

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholder to show default image while a request is in progress

```
Glide.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
  .into(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!imageUrl.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            imageView?.let { iv ->
                Glide.with(iv.context)
                        .load(AppUtility.IMAGE_THUMB_URL.plus(imageUrl))
                        .apply(options)
                        .into(iv)
            }
        } else {
            imageView?.setImageDrawable(error)
         // set here your error img
        }
```